# Find if-nodes that are immediately followed by a raise-node in Python with libcst

Tags: python, abstract-syntax-tree, libcst

right now I am working on a project for a university course. I got some random functions and most of them have a if-raise-statement in the code somewhere.

I try to find those, but only those 1 or 2 lines. I transform the functions into an AST and then visit it using libcst. I extend the visitor class, search for if-nodes and then match for raise-nodes. However this also matches and saves statements that are like if-if-raise or if-else-raise.

I hope someone can help me on how to modify the matcher to **only match if-nodes directly followed by 1 raise node**. (Sequence wildcard matchers would be awesome, but as far as I understand it they cannot be matched to find sequences of nodes.)

```
import libcst as cst
import libcst.matchers as m

class FindIfRaise(cst.CSTVisitor):

    if_raise = [] 

    # INIT
    def __init__(self):
        self.if_raise = []

    def visit_If(self, node: cst.If):
        try:
            if m.findall(node, m.Raise()):
                self.if_raise.append(node)
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Instead of a node visitor pattern, you can recursively traverse the `cst`, navigating via the `body` attribute of each `cst` object. This way you can track your depth, check for sibling `if` statements, and only produce `raise` statements when the desired conditions are met:

```
import libcst as cst
def walk(ct, p = []):
  bd = ct
  while (not isinstance(bd:=getattr(bd, 'body', []), list)): pass
  for i, t in enumerate(bd):
     if isinstance(t, cst._nodes.statement.Raise):
        f = False
        for i in p[::-1]:
           if not isinstance(i, (cst._nodes.statement.IndentedBlock, cst._nodes.statement.SimpleStatementLine)):
              f = isinstance(i, cst._nodes.statement.If)
              break
        if f: yield t
     elif isinstance(t, cst._nodes.statement.If):
        if t.orelse is None and (i == len(bd) - 1 or not isinstance(bd[i + 1], cst._nodes.statement.If)):
           yield from walk(t, p + [t])
     else:
         yield from walk(t, p + [t])
```

```py
s = """
if something:
   raise Exception
if something_else:
   pass
"""
print([*walk(cst.parse_module(s))]) #[], since `if something` is followed by another if-statement
s1 = """
if something:
   raise Exception
elif something_else:
   pass
"""
print([*walk(cst.parse_module(s1))]) #[], since `if something` is followed by an elif-statement
s2 = """
if something:
   raise Exception
for i in range(10): pass
"""
print([*walk(cst.parse_module(s2))]) #[Raise(
#    exc=Name(
#        value='Exception',
#        lpar=[],
#        rpar=[],
#    ),
#    cause=None,
#    whitespace_after_raise=SimpleWhitespace(
#        value=' ',
#    ),
#    semicolon=MaybeSentinel.DEFAULT,
#)]
```

Comment: This goes against the point of using libcst. Using isinstance() is not a good sign here.

Answer (score 2):

You'd want something like this:

```py
import libcst.matchers as m

maybe_more = m.AtLeastN(m.DoNotCare(), n=0)  # anything or nothing
raise_block = [m.Raise(), maybe_more]  # raise followed by anything or nothing
single_line_body = m.SimpleStatementSuite(body=raise_block)
multi_line_body = m.IndentedBlock(
    body=[m.SimpleStatementLine(body=raise_block), maybe_more]
)
if_raise = m.If(body=single_line_body | multi_line_body)
```

This should match all of the following `if` statements:

```py
if foo: raise Bar(); blah()
if foo: raise Bar()
if foo:
    raise Bar()
if foo:
    raise Bar()
    blah()
if foo:
    raise Bar(); blah()
```